# Export multiple datasets to one Excel sheet in Matlab

Tags: excel, matlab, dataset

Hej,
I have some data, which i want to export to Excel.
The data consists of several sequences, and each sequence is stored as a dataset.
Normally, the 'dataset' class is quite neat, allowing to store variable and observation names. Therefore, I would like to keep it.

For single datasets i use the 'export' function (as opposed to 'xlswrite'), e.g.:

```
export(Data, 'XLSfile' ,[pathname '\' filename],'Sheet',1);
```

This writes the dataset 'Data' to the specified spread sheet.

Now I want to export multiple datasets to 1 spread sheet.
Thus, I can't use the 'export' function anymore (as far as I know).

I know that I can specify the range with the function 'xlswrite' and make a nice loop, e.g.:

```
for iSequence 1:nrSequences   
xlRange= ...;   
xlswrite([pathname '\' fname],Data{iSequence},sheetnumber,xlRange);   
end
```

This works fine if 'Data{iSquence}' is an array, BUT... it does not work with datasets.
Trying this with datasets produces the following error:

```
'Error using xlswrite (line ...)   
Input data must be a numeric, cell, or logical array.'
```

So, does anybody know, how to do this?

Comment: You may have noticed that using [`dataset` is not suggested](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/dataset.html), and you should make the transition to [`table`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html). Then, you could also use [built-in functions that support table-to-Excel export](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/writetable.html). In order for us to recommend to you the right way to store your data (and possibly confirm that storing it as `dataset` is the only way), you should provide an example of your data in the question.

Comment: 'Table' does the trick! I simply wasn't aware, 'dataset' is outdated. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<<*This is a copy of the suggestion from my comment that appears to have solved the OP's problem*>>

You may have noticed MathWorks' notification in the documentation for [`dataset`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/dataset.html):

> The `dataset` data type might be removed in a future release. To work with heterogeneous data, use the MATLAB® `table` data type instead. See MATLAB [`table`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html) documentation for more information.

Therefore, you should likely make the transition to [`table`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html). Then, you could also use [built-in functions that support table-to-Excel export](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/writetable.html).